# PaaS (Platform as a service) for PHP

Tags: php, paas

I have walked a long road, finding out all possible 'AppEngine' for PHP solutions and am still not where I would like to be. Here is what I have seen so far:

- pagodabox.com

  - I love these guys. They have built the best looking admin interface I have ever seen, combined with great ideas in mind like Memcache, MongoDB support (both coming) and seamless Github deployment. Unfortunately I just learned that they do not support concurrent requests on a single server. The support staffer literally told me I would need an additional server for each concurrent request I will get.
    (**UPDATE**: In Oct 2011 they apparently changed this and say: "[App instances can now process concurrent requests.](http://www.newpagodabox.com/features/release-notes)")
- phpfog.com

  - Did play a little with it. They do not support GitHub and you are tied to their Git server -you might like this or not. But you also have to pay for boxes. Shouldn't a cloud service give me the opportunity to use multiple machines, but look like one? Here I can only see one instance. So where is the benefit? Less administration?
- cloudcontrol.com

  - Correct me if I am wrong, but they seem to do pretty much the same as PHPFog.
- scalarium.com

  - Looks great, costs a lot. If it actually does what it promisses, the only one that really seams to make sense to me. Did not get a chance to try it out yet.

I am dying for alternatives!

Comment: Is there a question lurking in here?

Comment: Well, I wanted to hear, what you guys experienced. Sorry I did not make it clear in my post. However I decided to use my own servers now. Not the way everybody goes today, but works for me best.

Comment: http://www.paaslist.com/ you can compare different kind of paas platform.

Comment: pagodabox is horrible. we used them for about 6 months and got bitten badly on numerous occasions. Unstable as hell. Unfortunate, too - as they have probably the best features aimed squarely at devs.

AppFog we gave up on - we were with them when they were PHPFog, same problems. Too unstable, regular downtime, and then a forced moved as they were shutting down PHPFog. Result - no more business with them.

Am about to try FortRabbit. Already annoyed, their UI is crappy and I've found it quite difficult to figure out how the hell I get things moving...

Comment: For anyone else who finds this; all of the above services are now defunct.